# display: block; does not fix overlap

Tags: css

Per this page at my site.  http://kaizenkarateacademy.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3&Itemid=114.  I have two columns that scaffold.  The first column holds a contact form and the other a Google Map.  The problem is that the two  columns overlap the footer div.

How do I make

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-8 tut-block alt"> Contains Sendmail form</div>
```

and

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 tut-block">Contains a Google Map Iframe </div>
```

to bump/push down

```
<div id="rt-footer">
```

I've spent three hours on a solution with zero success. I've assumed `display: block;` is the solution but it does not fix the overlap problem.  I've also tried `display: table;` with no joy.

Wow...this really confuses me.

Comment: Show your CSS. Make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem with the minimum necessary code.

Comment: Why do you expect `display: block` to fix an overlap?

Comment: I tried to add a css property in #footer and it works in firebug. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Are the scaffold children floated? try adding

```
clear: both;
```

in the `#footer`. I tried it in firebug and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```css
#body-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
```

or this

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

or better remove both.

you would see what's happening there using your browser's developer tools.